# Перестали загружаться и редактироваться главные изображения товара woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, изображения, woocommerce

Перестали загружаться и редактироваться главные изображения товара woocommerce.

При редактировании товара в админке есть возможность выбрать из галереи изображение, выбираю нужное изображение, но ничего не происходит.
Загруженные в другие товары главные изображения также не возможно поменять или удалить. Только путем удаления самого изображения с сервера.

Хелп
сайт http://kavkazskitur.ru/ekskursii-po-severnomu-kavkazu/
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ничего из описания проблемы не понятно. Сначала зайдите в консоль и посмотрите ошибки. Первым делом у Вас на сайте и без картинок ошибка выполнения скрипта ответственного за Google аналитику и tag.js . Сначала устраните её, поскольку JS ошибки не редко мешают работать остальным скриптам.

Comment: Вангую место на хостинге закончилось